# This expression was expected to have type 'Label.Option' but here has type 'HTMLAttr'

Tags: fable-f#, elmish

[i am trying add styling to a label in a form as shown in picture but i am getting error as shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuUg9.png)

Answer (score 0):

When using Fulma, you have access to 3 specials helpers on each Fulma component:

- `CustomClass` allows you to pass a custom class
- `Props` allows you to pass any standard html property (aka `HTMLAttr`)
- `Modifiers` allows you to add Modifiers coming from Fulma (like `Modifier.IsHidden` for example).

You should probably read this [page](https://fulma.github.io/Fulma/) to know more about Fulma in general

In your case, you want to write something like that:

`Label.label [ Label.Props [ Style [ BackgroundColor "yellow" ] ]`